# Jetty application throwing SaxParseException

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jetty

I am trying to run a basic Jetty application in Mac OS X 10.10. I am following this example - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128145/Run-Jetty-Web-Server-Within-Your-Application.

Since the system uses JRE 6, I am using Jetty 8. After doing everything, when I run the application, the button comes alright, and clicking it shows the first two lines in the following log message (in red, which looks like to me as an error, even though no error message is shown). However, when I open the web-page `http://localhost:8585/runJetty/`, I get the remaining lines as error, and the web-page shows an `Error 500` message - `Problem accessing /runJetty/. Reason: Server Fault`

```
    2014-11-02 21:49:31.388:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.16.v20140903
2014-11-02 21:49:32.398:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8585
2014-11-02 21:49:59.100:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /page/index.jsp(2,43) PWC6212: equal symbol expected
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:81)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:376)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttribute(Parser.java:253)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:203)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:216)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.getPageEncodingForJspSyntax(ParserController.java:517)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.determineSyntaxAndEncoding(ParserController.java:460)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:215)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:145)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:212)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:572)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
2014-11-02 21:49:59.103:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:/runJetty/
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /page/index.jsp(2,43) PWC6212: equal symbol expected
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:81)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:376)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttribute(Parser.java:253)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:203)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:216)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.getPageEncodingForJspSyntax(ParserController.java:517)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.determineSyntaxAndEncoding(ParserController.java:460)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:215)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:145)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:212)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:572)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here? If it helps, this is my directory structure (the **Referenced Libraries** contains all the Jetty jar files necessary):

[image]

And here is the `web.xml` file in the `WEB-INF` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app version="2.4">
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>page/index.jsp</welcome-file> 
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the web.xml file, a namespace is defined twice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"   <-- HERE
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"   <-- AND HERE
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
   <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>page/index.jsp</welcome-file> 
   </welcome-file-list>
  </web-app>
```

Remove one of them

Comment: Thanks. Did that. Still getting some errors, as I have updated my question to include that.

Comment: You can add xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" in your web-app tag

Comment: Did that, and again getting a different error. Updating the error log and including the current `xml` file as well.

Comment: No, closing tag was missing. Fixed it, now getting missing jar error. Will add those jars and let you know.

Comment: Updated the question, fixed the `web.xml` errors, but now getting errors while launching the web page..

Comment: Working now, there were some problems with the opening tag in the `index.jsp` file. Thanks a lot.